# Como eliminar objetos criados dinamicamente com base em vetor? (VBA/Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

O código abaixo cria Labels dinamicamente com base em um vetor, ocorre que não tive sucesso ao tentar eliminar (destruir) estes objetos.

Testei o 'Nothing' e outros recursos indicados, mas nenhum funcionou, ou seja, os Labels permanecem no formulário. Como na aplicação cada projeto que for selecionado terá um número diferente de Labels a serem criados, preciso destruí-los ao mudar de projeto (sem mudar ou fechar o formulário).

Apresento o código abaixo de uma das tentativas para destruir os Labels, porém não funcionou. Uma observação: também tentei destruir os Labels criados dentro da própria rotina de criação (ao final dela) para efetuar testes, mas também neste caso não funcionou.

Como devo fazer isso?

```
Private Sub CriaLabels(ByVal QuantidadeDeLabels As Integer)

Dim i As Integer

Dim NewLabel(QuantidadeDeLabels-1) As Object

For i = 0 To QuantidadeDeLabels-1

 Set NewLabel(i) = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

 With NewLabel(i)
  .Tag = "NewLabel" & (i-1) 'Usar no lugar de "Name"
  .Caption = .Tag 'Name inicia do Label2 pois existe o Label1 no formulário
  .Top = 50 * i
  .Left = 50
End With

Next i

End Sub



Private Sub DestroiLabels(ByVal QuantidadeDeLabels As Integer)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To QuantidadeDeLabels-1

 NewLabel(i).Delete 'NÂO FUNCIONOU ASSIM!!!

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para excluir o *label* deve-se utilizar da mesma forma como na construção:

```
Private Sub deleteLabel_Click()

Dim MyLabel(0) As Object

Set MyLabel(0) = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

    With MyLabel(0)
        .Name = "Label99" 'Nome de seu Label
    End With

    Me.Controls.Remove MyLabel(0).Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Funcionou! Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Evert, a solução apresentada só funciona dentro da mesma rotina, quando criei uma rotina em separado para apagar estes objetos, não funcionou.

Fiz várias tentativas e cheguei a uma solução que pode ser aprimorada, por exemplo, para o caso de se ter objetos de tipo diferentes criados no mesmo formulário (como Labels e TextBox) sem ser em ordem crescente:

```
Private Sub DestroiLabels(ByVal QuantidadeDeLabels As Integer)

Dim i As Integer

For i = Me.Controls.Count - 1 To Me.Controls.Count - QuantidadeDeLabels Step -1

  Me.Controls.Remove (Me.Controls(i).Name)

Next i

End Sub
```